# Can't parse data into setState of reactjs from my API

Tags: reactjs, axios

I made an API request with axios, received my data, and then parsed them with

`dp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data.data));`,

but when I want to call `setState` on these data and provide them to my whole app using Context API where my state contains the following:

```
state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
```

and call `this.setState` in my `componenetDidMount()` like so:

`this.setState({data: dp});`

However, this throws the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

PS: I have deep nested objects in my API call, so I can't define their properties in my state.

## UPDATE

```
 render () {
    return (
      <CoinContext.Provider 
        value={{
          data: this.state.data
        }}>
      </CoinContext.Provider>
    );
  }
```

value of dp: 
[result of dp request in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6HIu.png)

## UPDATE 2

context.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext({
    data: []
})
```

app.js:

```
import axios from './axios-coins';
import CPContext from './context/context.js'


class App extends Component {

    state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };

componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
}

fetchData() {
  axios
    .get("")
    .then(response => {
      data1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data.data));
      console.log(data1);
      this.setState({data: data1});
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}

render () {
    return (
      <CoinContext.Provider 
        value={{
          data: this.state.data
        }}>
      </CoinContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`? doesn't it look strange to you?

Comment: I made a call like with axios and I passed the response and I thought I could iterate through it but even though I remove it and assign the response.data.data directly with setState it shows the same error

Comment: What is the value of `dp`? Can you post some parts of it at least? Also, please show your `render` function

Comment: I made an update, take a look please

Comment: To pass a prop, you define the name as an attribute on the element like you did with value, not as an Object key as you are with data.  If you want a prop named data you'd do ```data={this.state.data}```. If you want the prop name to remain value, you'd pass it as ```value={this.state.data}```.  To the point, the error is from React trying to render the JS object you passed into the value prop.  As the message states, pure objects are not valid to be rendered by React, it must be an expression, value or JSX etc.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington but I mentioned that I have a nested objects which I need to iterate through them in my child component when I pass them within my context

Comment: That won't be an issue.  You can pass an array as props and then [map](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) through the values to render them all.

Comment: I quite didn't understand you :\ can you pass your solution so I can take a look at it

Comment: Provide more code if you want help. This isn't enough context.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I made a second update, take a look

Comment: `CPContext`/`CoinContext`?

Comment: I've fixed that into CPContext and it's not the reason of the error :\

Comment: Can't see why you would be getting `Invariant Violation` here. I don't even see you referencing the actual context data anywhere. (You haven't even defined children for the context provider).

Comment: Your code looks okay for me, can you try returning something inside like: `<CPContext.Provider value={{ data: this.state.data }}><div>Test</div></CPContext.Provider>`

Comment: I already tried something like that and passed my child component then I got this error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys